# Setting value For TextBox for Selected Href In Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have a loop that generates several rows of records. Each row has a href tag and an input box i would like to set the value of 'path' only for the each input item in that row to he same value. Under is the code:

```
<c:forEach items="${crime.victims}" var="victim" >
<div class="names">
<form:input path="${pvalue}" id="victims" value="${victim.socialSecurityNumber}" />
<a class="crimeNames" href="${victim.socialSecurityNumber}">${victim.name}</a>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: can u explain clearly

Comment: This isn't powered by plain' ol Javascript.  Smells like a templating library to me.  Can you tag the question properly?

Comment: Are you expecting the condition like,  <form:input path="${pvalue == victim.socialSecurityNumber ? pvalue : ''}" id="victims" value="${victim.socialSecurityNumber}" />

Comment: This is spring form tags which allows databinding the path really maps back to class attribute.